# Windows 8.1 & manual removal of "Sentinel Runtime Drivers"

Tags: windows-8.1

I'm trying to install Windows 8.1 (basic upgrade from Windows 8).  It is complaining of Sentinel Runtime Drivers incompatibility.  I've looked for it in my Programs & Features list, but it's not there by that name nor SafeNet (as related by google search) nor do I see any obvious candidates for it having been bundled with another listed application.  I tried the "Sentinel Runtime Driver Cleanup" program from the SafeNet website.  It ran but was ineffective, even after a reboot.

Do you recognize this "Sentinel Runtime Drivers"?

I ran MalwareBytes too, just in case, but it found nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer was that Lightworks didn't uninstall correctly (left shortcuts and this crappy license verification service running - what trash!)

This link finished it off:

http://amindlost.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/uninstalling-the-sentinel-license-service-hasplms/

Which says get this: http://sentinelcustomer.safenet-inc.com/DownloadNotice.aspx?dID=8589947873

And run it like this:

```
haspdinst.exe -purge
```

(I stopped the service first)

Comment: Here's the generic download link (rather than a specific version): http://sentinelcustomer.safenet-inc.com/sentineldownloads/  Search for `command line run-time installer`.  Also, use the `-remove` switch instead of `-purge`; it uninstalls everything, rather than just removing the service

Answer (score 5):

Steps involved:

1. Open the link:  [sentinelcustomer.safenet-inc.com/sentineldownloads](http://sentinelcustomer.safenet-inc.com/sentineldownloads/)
2. Click on: Sentinel HASP/LDK - Command Line Run-time Installer
3. It will download a compressed folder named: **Sentinel_LDK_Run-time_cmd_line**
4. Unzip this folder and copy its address
5. Open the command prompt by typing `cmd` from the run window or from the search (if using Win 7 or 8)
6. In the command prompt window, type `cd`, (space), and paste the copied address and press enter.
7. After that, while still in the command prompt, type `haspdinst -remove` and press enter.

   It will take some seconds to uninstall and once done, it will prompt you.